# Can anyone figure out how to manually trigger the animation of this piechart (XYPieChart)?

Tags: ios, core-animation

Can anyone take a look at the [XYPieChart](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart/tree/master/XYPieChart) files and see if there is a way to manually trigger the animation. I already tried `reloadData` but that doesn't do it.

You can grab the demo from github and add a button and try various methods to kick the animation off. As I said `[self.pieChartLeft reloadData]` won't do it.

Comment: Do you have the data source set before you call the reload data method?

Comment: Im my implementation, yes. If you could explain how to trigger it in the demo then I could move on from there.

Comment: And are you sure that you're changing the data/content before reloadData? Otherwise it of course won't animate. Which exact animation are you trying to kick off? The one where you clear the chart and then show it again? Or something different?

Comment: That's why I said "manually trigger". I already have the pie chart animation trigger automatically when the data changes. The animation I want is the pieChart filling up. That's to say I am sure that I am not changing the data / content before reload.

Comment: Additionally I've tried emptying the pie chart and putting the same info back in, methods such as `[_slices removeAllObjects]` then I repopulate the slices array but when it's the same info nothing happens. - like I said though if you can show me on the Demo then great I'll run with that.

Comment: I see, let me write an answer for that :)

Comment: Cheers for this Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it you are looking for the animation of the chart filling up.

To achieve that, you first have to remove all the elements and `reloadData` afterwards **then wait until the animation finishes** and only after that add all the elements again and `reloadData` again.

So, to show it on the demo, I've just modified the `clearSlices` method in the `ViewController.m` file to this:

```
- (IBAction)clearSlices {
    [_slices removeAllObjects];
    [self.pieChartLeft reloadData];
    [self.pieChartRight reloadData];

    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            [_slices addObject:@(rand()%60+20)];
       [self updateSlices];
    });
}
```

The delay of course has to be equal to your animation length. Try it out and see if thats what you want, otherwise leave a comment and I'll find a way how to fix it.

I also think that the XYPieChart is a little bit messy and could be improved - there should be methods for animating the chart manually (as what you want to do). Maybe I'll make a fork :)

**EDIT**
You could tweak your code a little if you don't want to remove the data entirely by adding an instance boolean variable, let's say `BOOL _showAnimationOnly` or anything to your liking. And then in the delegate method `pieChart:valueForSliceAtIndex:` you would just provide 0 if this boolean is YES. You have to control that variable of course, setting it on and off at different places (depends on your code). Something like this:

```
- (IBAction)animateSlices {
    _showAnimationOnly = YES;
    [self.pieChartLeft reloadData];
    [self.pieChartRight reloadData];

    double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
       _showAnimationOnly = NO;
       [self.pieChartLeft reloadData];
       [self.pieChartRight reloadData];
    });
}
```

Comment: Great. I'll try this out and give it a shot. Incidentally, in my project I'll navigate to a tab bar view and sometimes the animation will have already happened 'off screen' so to speak. Whilst XYPieChart is certainly a useful project it does seem somewhat unfinished from a general purpose point of view.

Comment: Where are you getting this 'updateSlices' from, did you write that and forget to include it? I'm getting a no visible interface in my demo...

Comment: That `updateSlices` is a method inside the demo `ViewController` class.

Comment: Yes it is, I accidentally typo'd that after pasting in your answer.. Silly.

Comment: Tested this in my demo and indeed it will trigger the animation. It's not exactly 'manually triggering the animation' so to speak since you need to empty the pie chart and put the data back in again, but it works, I appreciate the time and effort. Thanks.

Comment: If you do make a fork then if you'd edit this answer to include a link to the fork and whatever methods you add that'd be great. I've already accepted this as the answer in the mean time.

Comment: Check the edit to the answer, there is a simple way how **not to remove** the contents and still do the animation.

Comment: Yep great that's it, spot on. I'm sure that other people using this pieChart will appreciate that. It is fairly straight forward now I've seen the code, but that's always the way of it!

Comment: This solution is great but it forces the pie to animate twice:
- Once when reloadData is called with no values (make it disappear in 0.5 seconds)
- Once again when reloadData is called again with the new values (animate the pie in 0.5 seconds).

If you only want the second animation, set animationSpeed to 0 before calling reloadData the first time and then set it back to 0.5 before the second call